# Can I delete (apparently) redundant elements between my two Windows PATH variables?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

For some reason--and I'm not sure if this is standard on Windows--I've got 2 PATH variables in my Windows System settings under Environment Variables.

[image: Windows Environment Variables]

Can I delete from one of them anything that already exists in the other?  Is there some difference between them that would justify keeping everything in both places?

***Update***: I have Administrative access to my laptop (even though it is a corporate machine) and there is no other user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's normal - one is the User-specific PATH (`HKCU\Environment\PATH` in the registry) and the other the System PATH (`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\PATH`). Note that the User PATH environment variable is not present by default when a new account is created, and is either created manually if required or by a user-installed program.

If you must clean them up then delete the duplicates in the User PATH. The User PATH is appended to the System PATH, and the latter is common for all users. You can see the combined value by using the `PATH` or `SET` commands. Remember that any changes to these variables will not be reflected in already open command prompt windows.

Comment: It's completely normal, don't fiddle with it or you'll probably end up breaking something in an obscure way.

Comment: @Bigbio2002: Yeah, but as long as one's careful it's fine. The editing UI is horrible though. We really need a textbox there rather than one long horizontally scrolling text field.

Comment: To add to what has been said, if you're the only user on the system, you won't even notice the difference, but with multiple, there are common scenarios where it is beneficial for each user to have their own environment variables. And as @Karan said, fiddle with the User PATH variable, not the system one, as that is far more important and things that must run before the user is logged in may depend on it.

Comment: @Karan: oh my, the UI truly *is* ***horrible***.  I have to copy everything to a text editor and replace the separators with line breaks before I can edit anything, and then reverse the process to put it back.

Comment: @iconoclast: Yep. I'm sure someone must have come up with an envar or PATH editor, but this is just one of those things where a usable default UI should have been a no-brainer.

Answer (score 1):

No - one is the *system* path, and one is *yours*, which is added to the system path.  Open a command-window and type `path` to see the result.

If you arbitrarily delete from the *system* path things that happen to append in the *user* path, you will likely interfere with processes which you do not own.  Just because you are the "only" user on the system, for instance, does not mean that all of the processes — even those which you initiate — run with the same environment and permissions. (Deleting from the *user* path is safer, but this distinction was absent from the question).

In discussing redundant paths, there are at least two cases:

- the same directory, repeated
- executables with the same name but in different directories.

Identifying repeated directories is simplest on the fully-substituted path from the command-line.  In the system environment variables dialog, you can have symbols which will later be substituted.

As one of the comments notes, editing the path in the dialog is cumbersome, due to the poor user interface.  I generally review the path using the Windows port of [`conflict`](http://invisible-island.net/conflict/conflict.html), which lets me see where various programs are located along the path.  In [documenting](http://invisible-island.net/conflict/conflict.html#path-analyze) this a while back, I found a couple of related questions regarding ways to show your `PATH` in readable form:

- *[Pretty print' windows %PATH% variable - how to split on ';' in CMD shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471556/pretty-print-windows-path-variable-how-to-split-on-in-cmd-shell)*
- *[Is there an equivalent of 'which' on the Windows command line?](http://s%20there%20an%20equivalent%20of%20'which'%20on%20the%20Windows%20command%20line?)*

Comment: "No" to the question whether I can delete redundant items?  Why not? The rest of your answer doesn't support the "no" response.  Why would I want the path repeated?